# Facebook accountkit integration in Signup page

Tags: android, facebook, android-layout, android-studio, account-kit

I have successfully integrated Facebook account kit. Now I want to use it within my signup page. As Facebook account kit provide a different page for writing a phone number and another for verify otp. But **I want to take phone number from signup page and directly go to verification page (enter otp page).**

I have gone through the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/android)

I have followed all steps and successfully created a simple demo as per the doc.

Please let me know if you required any code. Please suggest any links or tutorial for the same

Comment: You created a demo... and then what? What is the problem you have?

Comment: No error in that demo. It is perfectly working. Now i want to integrate this process in my signup page. User will enter number in signup page and then redirect to Facebook enter otp page. Is it possible to do??

Comment: Well, you're supposed to try, and if / when you have a problem, then write a question. SO isn't the place for asking step-by-step instructions for something you haven't even tried to do.

Comment: That is what I am asking. Even i have mentioned in question if any code needed you can ask. As i don't know which code will be needed here. Now i am asking just which line from there to move for this requirement.

Comment: Please help if you know anything about this :( :(. I would really appreciate your help